# Can't compile ruby extensions: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set

Tags: ruby, gcc, 64-bit, rvm, native

I can't compile ruby extensions using RVM and ruby 2.3.0 (2.2.1 is the same), with message:
    city.cc:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
I'm using x86_64 Debian Wheezy, x86_64 ruby and gcc, on a 64bit CPU.
Despite that, seems that ruby uses `-march=native` which generates the problem. I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Details below:

Compiling an example extension:

```
gem install cityhash
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cityhash:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cityhash-0.8.1/ext/cityhash
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r  ./siteconf20160317-15208-1shn16g.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cityhash-0.8.1/ext/cityhash
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cityhash-0.8.1/ext/cityhash
make "DESTDIR="
compiling city.cc
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wdeclaration-after-statement’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-function-declaration’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
city.cc:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
make: *** [city.o] Błąd 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cityhash-0.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/cityhash-0.8.1/gem_make.out
```

The makefile is trying to run these commands:

```
$ make -n
echo compiling city.cc
g++ -I. -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.   -g -O3 -Wall -march=native -fPIC -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  -o city.o -c city.cc
echo compiling cityhash.cc
g++ -I. -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.   -g -O3 -Wall -march=native -fPIC -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  -o cityhash.o -c cityhash.cc
echo linking shared-object cityhash/cityhash.so 
rm -f cityhash.so
g++ -shared -o cityhash.so city.o cityhash.o -L. -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
```

uname, ruby, gcc versions -- all seem to be 64bit:

```
$ uname -a
Linux bukwica-prod 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u6 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
```

..although I don't know why for -match=native I get pentium-m

```
$ gcc -march=native -Q --help=target |grep march
-march=                             pentium-m
```

I'm out of ideas, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being [set explicitly in the gem](https://github.com/nashby/cityhash/blob/master/ext/cityhash/extconf.rb) (incorrectly)

```
%w{g O3 Wall march=native}.each do |flag|
  flag = "-#{flag}"
  $CPPFLAGS += " #{flag}" unless $CPPFLAGS.split.include? flag
end
```

Should be:

```
%w{g O3 Wall march}.each do |flag|
  flag = "-#{flag}"
  $CPPFLAGS += " #{flag}" unless $CPPFLAGS.split.include? flag
end
```

This [pull request](https://github.com/nashby/cityhash/pull/20) updates to remove march completely, but it's really old so don't count on anything changing there.

You can override where `bundle` pulls the gem from by putting this in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'cityhash', :git => 'git://github.com/lyfeyaj/cityhash.git'
```

That will install the forked version that contains the pull request

Comment: Thank you very much. I love You.